# Torch stop model forward at intermediate layer

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

Let’s say I have a 10-layer model that I want to run until random number layer at testing e.g. 8-th layer. When I want to run until 8-th layer, I don't need the result of 9-th and 10-th layer so I want it to stop at 8-th layer without extra expenses. How can I do this? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to load your pre-trained model, then you can remove any layer using `remove function` according to the Sequential Model defined [here](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/Sequential.lua).

Comment: Thanks, the random number will change in testing , I need to remove the network dynamic.